# Unable to access global temp tables of DB2 from SSIS

Tags: ssis, db2, etl, temp-tables

I have manually created global temp table in DB2 and trying to access the same in SSIS DFT. But i'm unable to access.

Note : Session is on open

Create script :

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temptbl
(id int ) 
WITH Replace 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Error Message:

> Unable to retrieve the column information from data source. Make sure target table in database is available

Comment: What's the exact command you used to create/declare a global temporary table? Provide exact error message you get instead of `unable to access`.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein added the needed info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table definition of the `DECLARED` global temporary table is not placed to the system catalog.
You should use a [`CREATED` global temporary table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053719.html) instead, if your tool wants to get such a definition from the system catalog.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temptbl
(id int ) 
WITH Replace 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```